# Create calendar with SAS/AF

Tags: calendar, sas, sas-af

I'm new here so sorry if I'm missing something... 
I'd like some help concerning SAS/AF, I'm looking to create a dynamic calendar, which means days are automatically displayed when the user goes through the years/months.

I created a dataset with the info I need to be displayed in the calendar :

```
%let fromDate = 31DEC2005;
%let toDate = 31DEC2016;
data calendar;

  do date = "&fromDate"d to "&toDate"d; 
    DayOfWeek = put(date, downame3.);
    Day = put(date, day.);
    Month=month(date);
    Year=year(date);
    output; 
  end; 

  format 
    date date9.
  ;
run;
```

What I'd like to do is create a frame that looks like the Windows calendar we have for example, but I don't know what component is the best to use here : Push Button or Container Box ?

I created a class via SCL code called Calendar, though I'm new to SAS too so I'm sorry I don't know where to start from with the class... I want to dynamically set the days (1-31) in the boxes (coming from the data set "calendar" above), when the user goes through years/months.

The user goes through years/months by clicking on a "scroll control" then displays the days afterwards.

Thank you for helping !

**EDIT :** I've made the frame using some properties, here's a look :
[calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHQ8B.png)

So what I still need to do is put the days (1-31) in the Push Buttons (I guess it's possible to do that with SCL via the .label). There's one problem though with the Spin Boxes, the data is set manually by me, in the Combo Boxes, it's set from the Data set I've created, is there a way to keep the Spin Boxes and link it to the Data Set instead ? like a list or something ? Enlighten me please u_u

Comment: What have you found out so far? What have you tried? Which problems did occur?

Comment: Hi thank you for stopping by !
I now have a data set with the dates (days, months, years), i want to make a class that puts everything in the proper place, and idk where to start from..

Also in the frame what component should I use ? do I have to make like 35 boxes ?

Comment: Please edit your question and add more details.

Comment: edited , thank you !

Comment: AF? SCL??? oh dear... ancient times you're living in. What version of SAS you are using? 6.2?

Comment: yes indeed, I have to work with SAS/AF for a project, don't really have a choice ... it's SAS 9.3

Comment: hello, I've been working on something and got an output out of it, so can someone close this subject, it's solved. Thank you !